Authorize actions in command handler
I have a problem with controllers authorization in C#. I use JWT authentication with token and role-based authorization in controllers.
Let's examine this endpoint.
    [HttpDelete("{userId}/post/{postId}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserPost(int userId, int postId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        _mediator.Send(new DeletePostCommand(userId, postId), ct);
        return Ok("Post deleted.");
    }

Does it mean that every person who has "User" roles can delete sombody else post?
For example authorized user with Id = 1 and role = "User" can call this endpoint with passing values like userId = 5 and postId = 20 (which are values for another user). This will cause deleting somebody's post by somebody else.
Is it a good solution to get authorized user Id from HttpContext and change the endpoint to something like this?
    [HttpDelete("post/{postId}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserPost(int postId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        _mediator.Send(new DeletePostCommand(postId), ct);
        return Ok("Post deleted.");
    }

UserId would be set in command-handler based on HttpContext and current authorized user instead of endpoint's parameter. Should it prevent user from deleting somebody's else post?

Yes, using the userId parameter directly in the endpoint allows any user with the User role to delete any other user's post.
you can retrieve the authenticated user's Id from the HttpContextand use it to ensure that users can only delete their own posts.
This is just an example:
[HttpDelete("post/{postId}")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserPost(int postId, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var userId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
    if (userId == 0)
    {
        return Unauthorized("Invalid user ID.");
    }

    _mediator.Send(new DeletePostCommand(userId, postId), ct);
    return Ok("Post deleted.");
}

Edit
It is a good practice to add such rule into your Custom Repository (DAL Layer if you're adhering to a similar n-layer architecture), So that your application validates the request with the rule being Post.UserId == Request.UserId for example.
IT helps keep your service and controller layers clean and focused on their primary responsibilities. (First principle of the SOLIDs)

I use clean architecture pattern. It means I have command-handler where I can validate user's id. So let's examine I have something like "IsUserOwnerOfPost(int userId, int postId)" method in the handler. It can check if user is expected to do anything related to the post, if he is not allowed then 401 should be returned.
Can you suggest some approaches or articles due to this authorization problem? I think role-based authorization is not enough. Maybe an approach with own helpful service that can check user's rights to make changes in database?

@JacobDev Simply put, here is what has changed my vision on solutions architectures overall:  The Standard, the best interpretation of SOLID principles for large scale enterprise applications. It has been mainly put together by Hassan Habib (a senior software engineer at Microsoft). You can check the Controllers section if you want but I recommend walking through the whole thing. Hope this helps in some way :)

Yes. At the moment everyone with the Role 'User' can delete any post.
If you want to prevent that users can delete post, they didnt created you should probably store the UserId in the Post and check it in the CommandHandler or directly in the Controller (Depending on what you prefer).
Something like:
    if(post.UserId != userId){
// Throw exception or return a result indicating the deletion failed because of authorization
...
}
//

Handle your deletion

